# does with_lock lock everything inside the block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, locking, pessimistic-locking

Does `with_lock` lock all models in the block or just the model itself? For example in the following are all the `item` models inside `with_lock` locked or is just the `entry` model locked?

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  enum state: [:pending, :posted]
    
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
 
  def post!
    with_lock do
      return unless pending?
      items.each { |i| i.post! }
      self.posted!
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`with_lock` gets a row-level pessimistic lock on a single instance. `with_lock` simply combines the lock and transaction statements into one, so it is equivalent to:

```ruby
Entity.transaction do
  entity_instance.lock!
end
```

You are calling `with_lock` inside a model, so you are actually doing `self.with_lock`. That is, you are obtaining a lock on the current instance of `Entity`. The individual `Item` records do not get locked unless you explicitly lock them as well. Changes to them do get included in the same parent transaction, though.

Comment: that was very clear and answered my question perfect. thank you